# ASP.NET Globalization -- Displaying dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization, globalization

Good morning,

Apologies for the newbie question.  I'm just getting started with ASP.NET internationalization settings.

Background info:

I have a website which displays a `<table>` HTML object.  In that `<table>` HTML object, I have a column which displays dates.  My server being in the US, those dates show up as `MM/DD/YYYY`.  Many of my users plug into this webpage through Excel, via the Data --> Import External Data --> Import Web Query interface.  My users, for the most part, are in the US, so those dates show up correctly in their Excel screens.

Now I need to make the webpage work for UK users.  As is, they are downloading the dates as `MM/DD/YYYY`, which makes their spreadsheets unusable since their regional settings are set to `DD/MM/YYYY`.

My question is:

How do I make it so the web server realizes that the incoming request has a `en-GB` culture setting?  I could engineer my own little custom workaround, but I'm sure I'm not the first programmer to come across this.  How do the pro's handle this?  I'm looking for a solution that would be relatively simple and quick to put up, but I don't want to just put some crappy buggy piece of my own logic togethe that I'm going to dread 6 months from now.

Thanks a lot in advance,
-Alan.

Comment: It's i18n not i13n.  Can somebody change that tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

- The <globalization> element also needs the attribute culture="auto".  The uiCulture attribute affects the language used to retrieve resources.  The culture attribute affects the culture used for formatting numbers an dates.
- As noted in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx), it is not a best practice to rely exclusively on browser settings to determine the UI culture for a page. Users frequently use browsers that are not set to their preferences (for example, in an Internet cafe). You should provide a method for users to explicitly choose a language or language and culture (CultureInfo name) for the page.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks.  I couldn't get the web.config to work, but with your first comment it all worked.  This way I don't have to write any code.  Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can allow the browser to set your UI culture automatically if you wish, by opening up the web.config, like this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>    
       <globalization uiCulture="auto" />
       ...
```

And then the culture set by the browser will be automatically set in your app.  This means that when you have the framework display date/time values, they will be formatted according to the current thread's UI Culture.

This will also help if you are using currency and/or localized text (however you have to provide the localized resources for each culture you support).

Answer (score 1):

You could also accept a query string parameter for overriding the culture settings.

Culture initialization should go in the Page.InitializeCulture method.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture ( )
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
    = Request.QueryString [ "culture" ] != null ? new CultureInfo ( Request.QueryString [ "culture" ] ) : CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  //base.InitializeCulture ( );
}
```

Usage: http://tempuri.org/page.aspx?culture=en-GB

Comment: Actually, this web page is being called from an Excel add-in.  I wouldn't wanto to much around with detecting the machine's regional settings out of VBA :).

Comment: Still, very good point on where I should be initializing the culture.